# net.sf.json.JSONException: Found starting '{' but missing '}' at the end

Tags: java, json, parsing, informatica

I am trying to parse a json data in informatica using java transformation

Data set:

```
{


         "Details": {
            "Address": "Other",
            "id": "87",
            "type": "Commercial",
            "Date": "12/07/2016"
         }

}
```

Java code:

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(INPUT);

JSONObject details= (JSONObject) json.get("Details");
String Address= details.getString("Address");
AddressOUT=Address;
String Id= details.getString("Id");
IdOUT=Id;
String Type= details.getString("Type");
TypeOUT=Type;
String Date= details.getString("Date");
DateOUT=Date;
```

External jar files:
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar
json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar
ezmorph-1.0.6.jar
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
json-lib.jar

Import packages:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.String;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
import net.sf.json.JSONSerializer;
```

I am getting below error:

```
Message: [ERROR] net.sf.json.JSONException: Found starting '{' but missing '}' at the end. at character 0 of null
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:499)
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.<init>(JSONTokener.java:85)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromString(JSONObject.java:1201)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:165)
    at net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:139)
    at net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:103)
    at net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(JSONSerializer.java:84)
    at com.informatica.powercenter.server.jtx.JTXPartitionDriverImplGen.execute(JTXPartitionDriverImplGen.java:153) .
```

Comment: try using jackson or gson

Comment: I tried using jackson-databind-2.9.0.pr4.jar and gson-2.8.1.jar. But still same error

Comment: Are you sure that your `INPUT` is what you think it is?

Comment: Yes, You are right input was not what I expected.

Comment: Better delete this question then

Comment: But I am facing another issue for now...

Comment: String jsonObject ="{\n\n\n \"Details\"{\n \"Address\": other,\n\"ID\": 87,\n \"Type\": comercial,\n\"Date\": 12/11/2017\n}\n\n}";
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonObject);JTXPartitionDriverImplGen.java:156 cannot find symbol
symbol : constructor JSONObject
location: class net.sf.json.JSONObject
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonObject);